# Live SDK Windows 8.1 connection error

Tags: c#, connection, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1, live-sdk

I'm trying to run photoSky example  provided by microsoft for Live SDK + XAML+ Windows 8 developers.  But I'm getting an error at the following statement:

LiveLoginResult authResult = await authClient.LoginAsync(new List() { "wl.signin", "wl.basic", "wl.skydrive" });

Exception Message "The network location cannot be reached. For information about network troubleshooting, see Windows Help. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800704CF)"

I have tried different versions of Live SDK but it didn't work either. My package manifest is set correctly and I checked all the capabilities that are needed like internet ...

Can you please help me?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-installed win 8.1 and everything worked perfectly :)